# Sorting the list according to start time from GraphQL

Tags: react-native, sorting, graphql

I am trying to sort the list from graphql according to the start time and I tried to pass sort with start_time, but graphql showing "GraphQLDocumentError: Unknown argument "sort" on field "list.start_time"."

```
query GetListById($ListID: ID!) {
  list_by_id(id: $ListID, sort: "start_time:desc") {
    id
    title
    start_time
    end_time

  }
}
```

Can anyone show me how can I sort the list into the front? Thanks

Comment: what is the library you are using 'Apollo'?

Comment: Yes Apollo library